# Share raw resource via WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-intent, resources, share, whatsapp

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + ContextID.getPackageName() + "/" + ResourceID));
share.setType("audio/*");
ContextID.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Condividi il suono"));
```

The above code works fine with Gmail, while Whatsapp gives a toast message like "Share a file failed, please try it again"

Maybe i've the same problem of this guy: [Intent.ACTION_SEND Whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638475/intent-action-send-whatsapp)

But how can i temporarily copy my resources on sd card and then share them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
InputStream in = ContextID.getResources().openRawResource(ResourceID);              

try 
{
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "lastshared.mp3"));  
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {}              

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/lastshared.mp3"));
share.setType("audio/*");
ContextID.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Condividi il suono \"" + TheButton.getText() + "\""));
return true;
```

manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi I'm using your code to send a `mp3` file through WhatsApp but I'm getting an error similar to `Failed to send, please try again`. Do you know how to overcome this? Thanks in advance

Comment: its working .. .if you try to share directly from assets, whatsapp will not allow you.

Comment: Grazie Mille!! well Done;)

Comment: you don't require WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, as it can be done via content provider. share your file via content provider instead of saving in external storage and then share

Answer (score 0):

please change this line from your code and you will be able to share
write `("audio/mp3")` as bellow instead `("audio/*")`

```
share.setType("audio/mp3");
```

this is because share type for whatsapp doesn't support `("audio/*")` or `("*/*")`