# aHow can I share a mp3 file to whatsapp? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, mp3, share, whatsapp

I want to share a mp3 file to whatsapp.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996353/share-raw-resource-via-whatsapp) on Stack Overflow, but the accepted answer does not work for me. If I try to share it with whatsapp it says "Sharing failed, please try again":

```
                    File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sound);

                try
                {
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "sound.mp3"));
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)
                    {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();}

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sound.mp3"));
                share.setType("audio/mp3");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Shared"));
```

Here is the full MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.aaron.sharetest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button shareBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final File FILES_PATH = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/data/com.example.aaron.sharetest/files");

        File sharefile= new File(FILES_PATH, "sound.mp3") ;
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(sharefile));


        shareBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);

        shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {




                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(

                        Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

                    if (!FILES_PATH.mkdirs()) {

                        Log.w("error", "Could not create " + FILES_PATH);

                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    finish();

                }


                File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bibikurz);

                try
                {
                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "sound.mp3"));
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)
                    {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sound.mp3"));
                share.setType("audio/mp3");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Shared"));



        }



        });
    }


}
```

Of course I wrote this line in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What do I have to do to share the mp3 file to whatsapp, etc?

I tried so many accepted answers, but no one of them worked for me.

This is what I get in my LogCat:

```
06-23 02:41:17.589 23924-23924/? W/Bundle: Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected ArrayList but value was a android.net.Uri$StringUri.  The default value <null> was returned.
06-23 02:41:17.659 23924-23924/? W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$StringUri cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                                               at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:838)
                                               at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:5481)
                                               at com.whatsapp.ContactPicker.k(ContactPicker.java:623)
                                               at com.whatsapp.ContactPicker.onCreate(ContactPicker.java:338)
                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)
                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2511)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1375)
                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23) or later. If this is the case, you mustimplement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Use file path and check memory card

File FILES_PATH = new File(

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),

"Android/data/com.examples(your package )/files");

File sharefile= new File(

FILES_PATH,

"demo.mp3") ;

putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(sharefile))

```
@Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(

            Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

            if (!FILES_PATH.mkdirs()) {

                Log.w(TAG, "Could not create " + FILES_PATH);

            }

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.need_external_storage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();

        }
```

Comment: I postet the whole MainActivity.java in my edited question. Is that right how I did it? Beceause it is still saying me "Sharing failed, please try again"

Comment: Cannot resolve method "putExtra". I postet the new whole MainActivity in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

> My "sound.mp3" file is located in the raw folder.

Your first two samples will not work, as they have nothing to do with a `raw` resource. They share a file that does not exist, from a directory that might also not exist.

> But here I dont know what "ContextID" or "ResouceID" is.

If this code is going where your first two code snippets went, `ContextID` can be replaced with `this`. If you are trying to share `res/raw/sound.mp3`, then `ResourceID` is `R.raw.sound`.

Comment: I edited my question. I deleted "ContextID" and changed "ResourceID" to "R.raw.sound". But also here I'm getting the error message "Sharing failed, please try again"

Comment: @OverflowStacker: Replace `Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sound.mp3")` with `Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "sound.mp3"))`. Also, never `catch` an exception without logging it, as if you are crashing in your disk I/O (e.g., you lack permissions), you are not finding out about it.

Comment: I edited my question. It is still not working, but I posted my LogCat

Comment: @OverflowStacker: You need to hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to write where you want. And that in turn requires that you implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: I edited my question and postet my whole MainActivity.java, is that right how I did it? Becauese it is still not working. But now I'm getting another LogCat entry, I also postet it in my edited question.